# how to check if LazyLoad.js is working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I want to preload images as the show up on the screen so I'm trying LazyLoad.js

**Is there any way I can test if lazyload.js is working?**

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Preloading is exactly the opposite to lazyloading. Preloading means loading images beforehand. Lazyloading means loading images only when they are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your developer console type:

```
 typeof($("img").lazyload) === "function"
```

If the output is true, then it is loaded correctly and should be working.

If you want to test the execution of lazy loading, I can recommend that you clear your browser's cache and try reloading.

In Chrome's Developer Console (F12), you can tweak the speeds and simulate modem speeds.  `Hit F12 -> Network tab -> Change the "No throttling" dropdown`.  Choose a slower speed to experiment.

Comment: Is this simple attribute like loading="lazy" working on any dynamic or static site?

Comment: Sorry, can you expand on your question in a new post perhaps?

Comment: Thanks and what should we do if the output was ```false```?
For me, it's not working properly.

Comment: @Matin then that means you are likely not including the lazyload script tag in your html.

Comment: @Scott I used this resource "https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/lazyload" and include the lazyload script tag in my html and still not working for me and printing ```flase```. Any other idea?

Comment: @Matin I bet you are calling `typeof($("img").lazyload) === "function"` before you included the script tag.  Put console.log statements next to the script tag, and again next to where you are calling this.  You should see the script tag console log fire first.  If not, open a new question with your details/code.